# Merging objects which contain nested Map objects

Tags: javascript, merge, lodash

I have multiple javascript objects I want to merge together recursively. 
The objects have some number properties which I add together when merging.
The objects also have some [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) properties. Here is example how my object looks in Developer Console:

```js
byGender:Map
    0:{"Male" => 9}
        key:"Male"
        value:9
    1:{"Female" => 11}
        key:"Female"
        value:11
byType:Map
    0:{"Teens" => Object}
        key:"Teens"
        value:Object
            byGender:Map
                0:{"Guys" => 7}
                    key:"Guys"
                    value:7
                1:{"Girls" => 10}
                    key:"Girls"
                    value:10
            total:17
    1:{"Chaperones" => Object}
        key:"Chaperones"
        value:Object
            byGender:Map
                0:{"Ladies" => 1}
                    key:"Ladies"
                    value:1
                1:{"Men" => 2}
                    key:"Men"
                    value:2
            total:3
total:42
```

I want to merge the values of these Map objects so all numbers of matching keys are added together.

I'm using [_.mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs#mergeWith) and the its customizer function. I can successfully merge the simple number properties, but how do I merge the Map objects too? Right now my customizer merger function is just replacing the Map object so the last one wins.
Here is my customizer function I'm using with _.mergeWith

```js
 var merger = function (a, b) {
    if (_.isNumber(a)) {
      return a + b;
    } else {
      return _.mergeWith(a, b, merger);
    }
  };
```

It's difficult to find answers when searching because "map" keyword just pulls up bunch of .map() results, instead of the Map object.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/assvfk2b/5/ for what you explained, but I am not sure what you mean by merging the map object can you please edit jsFiddle and tell me what exactly you need.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to show the actual data structure I'm working with. It makes use of the Map object in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a merger function that works. Not as elegant as I hoped but posting here in case anyone else is stuck with this.

The only downside is that it's not as general solution as I'd like. I think it would require changes to work well with different types of structures and recursion complexity.

```js
function merger(source, mergeTarget) {
    if (_.isNumber(source)) {
      return source + mergeTarget;
    } 
    else if (_.isMap(source)) {
        var newMap = new Map();
        source.forEach(function(value,key,root){
            var newValue = mergeTarget.get(key);
            if(_.isNumber(value))
                newMap.set(key,value + newValue);
            else if (_.isObject(value)){
                var newObj = {};
                _.mergeWith(newObj,value,newValue,merger);
                newMap.set(key,newObj);
            }
        });
        return newMap;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously too late to be helpful, but maybe it will help someone else?

Because Maps are Iterable, there's a pretty easy way to merge them actually:

```
const mergedMap = new Map([...map1, ...map2]);
```

To handle colliding values by merging them together, one option would be to use the [mapCollectInto](https://mattiasmartens.github.io/big-m/global.html#mapCollectInto) function in the [big-m](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-m) library I wrote for the purpose ([source code](https://github.com/MattiasMartens/big-m/blob/master/exports/maps.ts)):

```
const { mapCollectInto, reconcileAdd } = "big-m";

const mergedMap = mapCollectInto(
  map1,
  map2,
  reconcileAdd()
);
```

Alternatively, leaving `map2` unchanged:

```
const { mapCollect, mapConcat, reconcileAdd } = "big-m";

const mergedMap = mapCollect(
  mapConcat(map1, map2),
  reconcileAdd()
);
```